# Why is $g(\text{grad} W,\text{grad} W)=\text{const}$ when the integral curve of $\text{grad} W$ are geodesics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. On one hand, we have a vector field $\textbf{X}\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, where $\textbf{X}=\text{grad}  W$ for some $W\in C^{\infty}(M)$. On the other hand, we the integral curves of $\text{grad} W$ are geodesic.

How could I prove that 
$$g(\text{grad} W,\text{grad} W)=\text{const}?$$

This assertion is found in the book "Differentiable Manifolds a Theoretical Thysics Approach" of  Gerardo F. Torres del Castillo on page 140 equation (6.72).

Comment: Doesn’t geodesic mean the acceleration is zero?

Comment: The fact that we have a gradient field here is irrelevant. If the integral curves of $\mathbf X$ are, parametrized as they are by time, geodesics, then $\mathbf X$ has constant length. What is the definition of geodesic with which you are working?

Comment: @TedShifrin But the constant would be different on different intgeral curves?

Comment: Aha. Hats off to @ArcticChar for catching my sloppiness! So, for example, the fact that the vector field is conservative prevents something like $f(y)\partial/\partial x$ in the Euclidean plane. This should be a standard argument ...

Comment: Ideally the question statement would include your own attempts at the problem, but as a hint, note that the hypothesis implies that that $\nabla_{\bf X} {\bf X} = 0$ and that the desired conclusion is equivalent to ${\bf Y} \cdot (g({\bf X}, {\bf X})) = 0$ holding for all vector fields $\bf Y$. The l.h.s. of the latter equality can be rewritten using the Leibniz rule.